# Anyone get Articulate Storyline to have TinCan designate a custom URL for its endpoint?

Tags: tin-can-api, articulate-storyline

Their documentation says you can augment the tincan.xml file in the root like so :

```
<launch lang="und">http://my.lms.com/TCActivityProvider/story.html
    ?endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.lms.com%2Flrs%2Fendpoint%2F
    &auth=OjFjMGY4NTYxNzUwOGI4YWY0NjFkNzU5MWUxMzE1ZGQ1
    &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%20%5B%22First%20Last%22%5D%2C%20%22mbox%22%3A%20%5B%22mailto%3Afirstlast%40mycompany.com%22%5D%7D
    &activity_id=61XkSYC1ht2_course_id
    &registration=760e3480-ba55-4991-94b0-01820dbd23a2
</launch>
```

And now the endpoint will go to your specified url. But no matter what I do, the URL never changes, and all the JSON statements are sent to the root of where story.html is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set an endpoint in Articulate tincan storyline, it automatically appends **/statement/** the the endpoint as a result the url for the LRS endpoint is not recognized. You need to create a rewrite rule and direct the json by Articulate to the appropriate handle.

Comment: Just to append to this what I also found helpful. But that URL has to be the launch URL, or the URL used to access/open the Articulate file itself.